# How to change curl command to point to my github repo. or local disk code

Tags: linux, bash, curl, github, build

I have a bash file the builds a program and retrieves the code and some required libraries from Github.

I made changes to the code in my own fork. Since I am new to Github, I need to ask how can I change the bash code that builds the program to point to my fork or the code folder in my local disk.

The bash file contains this piece, I hide the repo. name and author for privacy:

```
if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
  echo "Downloading $FILE.."
  cd ${BUILDDIR}/downloads
  curl -OL https://github.com/author/program-name/archive/master.zip
fi
```

In GitHub, I access the original code through: `https://github.com/author/program-name`. It is not zipped.

My fork code is in:

```
https://github.com/my-name/program-name
```

The Question: I need to run my own modified code either from my fork or the local disk. How can I modify this in the bash file that builds the program to point to my own code instead of the originals code?

Comment: Hello. So, you want your `bash` file to download files (and folders) from `https://github.com/my-name/program-name` (which is a fork repo) instead of `https://github.com/author/program-name`? Just verifying. If yes, then try replacing the `curl` command in the `bash` file with `curl -OL https://github.com/my-name/program-name/archive/master.zip` - It should get the job done.

Comment: I don't have archive.

Comment: `archive` is always a part of URL pointing to the ZIP file. Example: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/archive/master.zip

Comment: @user9371654 Just like @vookimedio also said: Any Github repo (original or forked) has an **url** which points to an **archive** - It is the compressed form of **latest version** of that repo's **master** branch. Try this: Replace `my-name` and `program-name` in `https://github.com/my-name/program-name/archive/master.zip` and open it in a web browser - A file download should start.